# How to spy on a Method that belongs to an object not accessible from outside?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm very new to Mockito and I have a situation for which I can't find a solution. There's a method that I want to test using Mockito. The problem is that inside this method, there's an object created and **that object has a function** that I want to mock.

So for example, here is a small sample code which illustrates my issue:

```
public class ClassA {
    public functionDoingDBStuff() {
        //...........
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    final ClassA classAObj = null;

    public functionXYZ() {
        classAObj = new ClassA();

        classAObj.functionDoingDBStuff();
    }
}


@Test
MyTestFunction() {
    ClassB classBObj = new ClassB();

    // How can I access and mock functionDoingDBStuff() here?
}
```

So in `MyTestFunction()`, I want to test `functionXYZ()`, but mock the function `functionDoingDBStuff()` that is called inside `functionXYZ()`. By mock, I mean return a specific result that I want for the test. However function `functionDoingDBStuff()` belongs to an object that's created inside `functionXYZ()`, so I don't know how I can tell Mockito to access it from within `MyTestFunction()`. I hope you're able to understand what I mean.

Comment: This is the reason why objects should not create their dependencies themselves. Use [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) instead.

Comment: Consider *not* mocking `ClassA`. Note [unit tests](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) do not require mocking.

Answer (score 0):

To me if a piece of code can't be easily tested that suggests a problem with the structure of the code. Anyway, why does `new ClassA()` need to be done inside the `functionXYZ`? Can't be instantiated (better still injected) at Object level? If so you can inject a mock instance of ClassA.

If it still has to be instantiated within the method, may be instead of doing `new ClassA()`, it should be wrapped inside a factory method. Then you can mock the factory to return a mock `ClassA`.